# UIScrollview enable delete row by swipe

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, swipe

i have two views in a `UIScollView`. the first view is a normal view and the second view is a tableview. 
i want enable swipe to delete a row in the tableview just when someone swipe from right to left. if someone swipe from left to right you will see the first view.
swipe to delete a row is just possible when the scrollenabled of the `UIScollView` is NO. 
I have no idea when set the scrollenable no or yes.

is this even possible?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34362517/440168