# swipe to delete in a UITableView which is embeded in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, ios4, uiscrollview

I've encountered a problem the same as [UIScrollview enable delete row by swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929432/uiscrollview-enable-delete-row-by-swipe)
  It is a tableView and another view work as subViews of a scrollView , and I can't enable "swipe to delete" until I set the **scrollEnable** property of the scrollView to **NO** , but it brings another problem : I can't swipe between the tableView and another view
Is there any ways other than setting the **scrollEnable** property to enable "swipe to delete" ?
If not , when should I set `self.scrollEnable = NO`, and when should I set `self.scrollEnable = YES` to have the "swipe to delete" and "swipe between views" both work fine ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If , I'm not mistaken , the touches are consumed by the scrollview and the editing of the table is not happening because the table is not getting the touches. This can be resolved by subclassing the UIScrollView in order to snd the touches to the next responder too. So it's just a matter of overrwriting the touchesBegan, moved and ended. Will update the answer later today with the code needed as I am on the road now. Cheers!

EDIT:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(!self.dragging)
    {
        [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Just create a class that inherits from `UIScrollView` and in the implementation drop this code. This will make the scrollView to not swallow the touches, but pass them on. Obviously , when creating your scrollView use the class you just created instead of `UIScrollView`.
Sorry for the delay. Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

You need to use custom subclass of `UIScrollView`. It should works with table views in horizontal scroll views:

```
@interface MyCoolScrollView : UIScrollView

@end

@implementation MyCoolScrollView

// Allows inner UITableView swipe-to-delete gesture
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(nonnull UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return [otherGestureRecognizer.view.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]];
}

@end
```

Comment: @Peymankh You need to also include benjaminhallock's answer with this for it to work in iOS 11.

Answer (score 5):

I've successfully used

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

in a UIScrollView subclass containing the tableview to enable a UISwipeGestureRecognizer residing in the tableview to trigger instead of being swallowed by the "main" scrollview's gesture recognizers.

Answer (score 3):

@THOR's answer is okay, but if your `UITableView` is in a `UIScrollView`, you probably have another `UIView` in there too. When you scroll up on the `tableview`, you accidentally slide over to the "other view".

This will prevent the sliding, and allow you to swipe to delete.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
if (gestureRecognizer.state != 0) {
        return YES;
} else {
    return NO;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but here is the swift 4 version, working in iOS 11 for me (You would subclass UIScrollView):

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if (otherGestureRecognizer.view != nil && otherGestureRecognizer.view!.superview != nil) {
        return otherGestureRecognizer.view!.superview!.isKind(of: UITableView.self)
    }

    return false
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != .possible) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```