# UITableView inside a UIScrollView not responding to swipe events

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, swift3, uiscrollviewdelegate

My question is similar to a bunch of questions on stackoverflow (eg. [swipe to delete in a UITableView which is embeded in a UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379989/swipe-to-delete-in-a-uitableview-which-is-embeded-in-a-uiscrollview)) 
I need to implement a swipe action on a table view cell for a tableview controller which is a custom view embedded in a scrollview. However, the swipe events are not working properly and I understand the problem is that the UIScrollView is eating up the events for the UITableView so I tried out a bunch of options.

1) I subclassed the UIScrollView with the touchesBegan, touchesEnd etc methods but they never seem to get hit.

2) I could get hits on scrollViewWillBeginDragging but I am not sure how to call the responder for the UITableViewController from this.

3) I implemented a gesture recognizer in the tableviewcontroller class but that also didn't help.

I am confused as to how to go about so some code in **Swift 3** syntax would be really helpful.

Comment: can you send screenshot for design of delete button ?

Comment: Its exactly similar to this. https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2014/01/IMG_3743.png

Comment: The only difference being that the table view is embedded in a scrollview

Comment: this is do without scrollview . it is the default delete button for tableview .

Comment: I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: do you want to do this without scrollView ? because without scrollview you can do this .

Comment: Why is your table view in a scroll view? A `UITableView` already is a `UIScrollView`.

Comment: right... I want to do this with scrollview. Without the scrollview it already works.

Comment: @maddy - that's coz it's a composite vc which is a *sorta* tab bar and the scroll view actually implements the transition between the tabs. One tab in this is a tableview...

Comment: check this for your delete button : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29166246/3901620

Comment: @KKRocks: thanks I already have this working. My problem is that the swipe action doesn't always work properly because sometimes the scrollview eats up the swipe action. I need a way to propagate the swipe action to the tableviewcontroller. That's what I am looking for.